# Viewsonic VX2035wm fades black

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card

Short on cash, I need to determine where lies this recent problem with my 2-3 years old Viewsonic VX2035wm monitor fading black.  Here is what I have tried:

Initial problem with new motherboard Gigabyte 78LMT-S2P onboard video adapter, monitor begins to fades after month or so.  Serendipitously, it appears to occur after installing Adobe flash for Firefox to use. Chrome already has a plugin for flash, but Firefox needs the full flash install. I also had installed an old copy of SecondLife setup that failed to install in the past because I didn't have the right graphics chip/card. This time it installed with this new onboard video adapter.  But Secondlife complained it was an old client, so it auto-intalled a new client. I think it might has installed some other video/audio codecs, drivers.

When fading started, I uninstalled flash, secondcity and it appeared to resolve the problem.

It begin again. I tried the monitor on a laptop and it was fine.

I decided to try a graphics card, so I found an old Stealth 3D 2000PRO PCI card and it works fine. I am using it now to write this question.

However, the resolution is too low (1024x768) so I went to TigerDirect and got a NVIDIA GeForce 210 PCI Expressx16 card.   Plugged it in, booted up, Windows 7 (64bit) auto detected it and allowed me to set a higher resolution.

Moments later it faded. So its back on the old Stealth PCI card and its all fine.

So what is the problem?

- Gigabyte board going bad?
- Monitor going bad?
- Not enough power? 400 watts?

BTW, when the monitor fades out, there appears to be flashes like it wants to return back.  I can remote desktop into the machine just fine.   If I turn off the monitor and wait for 10 secs or so, it will come back for a few seconds and then fades again.

- Is there a device driver problem, perhaps?
- So green logic problem with the power saver?

I disabled the power saving turning off the monitor but I kept a 15 mins screensaver.

I'm broke but I need my computer with the higher resolution. I will get the monitor if need be but could it be a software issue or there is another card to try?